# Why can't I reference result of (defrecord Foo [bar]) in REPL after (load-file "foofile.clj")?

Tags: clojure

My file looks like this, more or less:

```
(ns foofile)

(defprotocol foo-protocol 
  "foo(lish example)"
  (foo-method [this] "foo docs")

(defrecord Foo [biz])

(def foo (Foo. "baz"))
```

I start the REPL and type

```
(load-file "foofile.clj")
```

and it prints

```
#'foofile/foo
```

Now I can reference foofile/foo and foofile/foo-protocol, but when I try foofile/Foo, I get

```
java.lang.Exception: No such var: foofile/Foo (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

The same (or substantially similar) code works just dandy if I manually enter in into the REPL (specifically, I followed [this blog post](http://freegeek.in/blog/2010/05/clojure-protocols-datatypes-a-sneak-peek/)). What's going on here? What's different between doing this in the REPL and loading a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import Foo, since it's a java class:

```
(import 'foofile.Foo)
```

The reason it works when you enter your code in a repl is that you're in the same namespace you declared Foo in when you're referring to `Foo` (probably the namespace `user`).